# modx replacing article link with a link of categories

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, modx, article

I've got a staging and live site I'm working on (not my code base). I've accidentally replaced the live server with some staging code (no backup (slap me)) and I'm getting weird urls for articles on the sites 'blog' page.

Basically everything's being called into the page correctly but the page header link is being screwed.

Rather than being

http://www.example.com/a-nice-url

it's giving me

http://www.example.com/news,recent,pr,etc

which appears to be the list of categories of the article.

Where/How can I easily fix this?

I'm only calling [[*content]] and can't find where that is.

Linking to an article I know is there with the correct url works still.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your blog page has some sort of listing somewhere, maybe a getResources call? If you can't find it in your blog list template (as you're saying you only see a *content), it means the list is probably "hardcoded" in the blog list resource content field.

You'll want to find the chunks being used to output each blog entry on the lists and check which page parameter is used to construct the link. It should probably be *alias, and if it is and your aliases are correct you have some deeper trouble going on.